# Custom updates.xml for user (Install4J)

Tags: java, install4j

I'm trying to implement a control of version per user, the problem is that I only know the user's ID when he runs the executable.
To do that have some options but I don't know witch one is the best and if it will work:

**Option 1:** 
Modify URL for updates.xml in runtime. It may be some variables on url (http://server.com/updates.xml?client=1) or change the url (http://server.com/updates-1.xml). It's possible? How can I set this variable on `install4J` context from my application and make updater installer use the same context?

**Option 2:**
In runtime on my application I download the `updates.xml` manually but how can I save on installer variable named "updateDescriptor" inside `install4j` context? The updater installer will use the same updateDescriptor that I set or will download it again from the URL for `updates.xml`?

**Option 3:**
Same as option 2 but instead save on context variable, I could save as a file on the application's folder and pass the file as argument [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170159/install4j-file-with-update-placed-in-my-local-directory) on URL for `updates.xml`, but how could I know witch folder is the application installed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see

[install4j - file with update placed in my local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170159/install4j-file-with-update-placed-in-my-local-directory?rq=1)

for how to change the URL for downloading updates.xml at runtime.

Comment: Hello, i linked this post on my question.. In the example the path was (file:///C:/path/to/updates.xml), there is a way to know where the application is installed, instead /path/to ? And where should i pass this args (-VmyUpdatesUrl) ?

Comment: The linked question was about having the updates.xml file in the local file system. In your case, replace the "file:///" URL with your URL where updates.xml can be downloaded from.

Comment: Ingo, is there a way to see the log of updater installer? because the updater open but closes suddenly..

Comment: The log file of the update downlader is in the %TEMP% directory as long as the update downloader is running. To prevent its deletion after a regular exit, pass `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true` to the update downloader. Another useful command line parameter is `-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=<path to writable log file>` to save the log file to another path.